# Best methods/tools/practices for releasing of a web based application

Tags: versioning, release-management, software-release

So I'm starting a web project from scratch on PHP/Zend Framework/SVN, and want to start it very structured. I know all about SVN branching, having a development branch, hot fix branch etc. (well at least I think I do).

My question is what's the best method to release new version of my software in the future, instead of just doing an `svn update`. For ex. deploy the new version to a test server for staging before releasing to production and such sort of things. Any thoughts?

Comment: I found Bamboo by Atlassian guys which is pretty slick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As step 1, I wouldn't use a tool built to manage source code versioning for deployment, I'd recommend a tool that can manage/deploy releases for that purpose :)

I am a support analyst for [BuildMaster](http://inedo.com/buildmaster), a tool which does exactly what you need (and it's free for you if you have a team of <= 5 people).

Comment: That's sort of what I was looking for, I would have to do some further comparison of similar products out there and analysis, before suggesting my team to use it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It really depends how your infrastructure looks like. If you are deploying to a lot of nodes I think using BitTorrent is a good choice

Comment: bittorrent? in the release of code? I'm dealing with a web application so my software will be SaaS, not an executable that users need to download

Comment: I meant so you can distribute the app to your servers. You don't have to put the torrent file on a public tracker